# Python Pandas prevent line break in cell

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following functions, I already managed to prevent truncation in the output in my notebook:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 200)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 0)
```

However, it still breaks long lines within some cells (not truncates!). How can I prevent it from doing that?

(I don't care how wide the total table will be, because I can simply scroll in the output of the notebook cell ...)

Comment: If you pass `-1` then there is no limit are you saying that you still have some columns with more than 200 characters?

Comment: Sorry, no all text is displayed but broken into multiple lines within one cell =(

Comment: try `pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)`

Comment: @EdChum doesn't change anything, still line breaks in the cells

Answer (score 35):

for me worked `pandas.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)` as suggested by @EdChum.

```
import pandas
matrix = [[None]*5]*4
matrix[1][1] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut"
matrix[1][4] = matrix[1][1]
print pandas.DataFrame(matrix) # will print the matrix,
# column 4 is completely underneath the other 3 columns with all rows


pandas.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
print pandas.DataFrame(matrix) # prints only one table (no break of columns)
```

Comment: Note that it works in `with pd.option_context(...)` as well.

Comment: Doesn't work in Jupyter 1.0.0, pandas 1.4.3, python 3.8.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, I'm using python 2.7, and tested it with 3.6 on the Pycharm IDE.

```
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="sheet", inplace=True, usecols="A,C:E")

    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 300, 'display.max_columns', 7, 'display.expand_frame_repr', False):
        print(df)

except:
    print ('failed')
```

However, for the Jupyter Notebooks, I believe this is the syntax:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

pd.DataFrame({'string_x': string_x}, index = [0])
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here worked in jupyter for me, what worked was appealing to CSS:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(f"<style>td{white-space: nowrap !important;}</style>")
```

I've not tested but this may work too:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'white-space: nowrap !important;'}])
```

Answer (score 0):

These setting is not work when str is chinese character.Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
num_columns = 25
data = {f'Column{i}': ['这是一个较长的字符串，可能会导致换行显示。', '短字符串1', '短字符串2'] for i in range(1, num_columns + 1)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)  # Limit the display to 20 columns
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)  # Adjust based on your needs
pd.set_option('display.unicode.ambiguous_as_wide', True)  # Consider Unicode characters in width calculation

def format_strings(val):
    return f'<div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">{val}</div>'

styled_df = df.style.format(format_strings)

styled_df.set_table_styles([
{'selector': 'table', 'props': [('width', '100%')]}
])

styled_df
```