# Dataframe column not showing in one line

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe imported from csv file and I have set option of *('display.max_colwidth', None)* still the column **(column named 'Week')** values (which are strings) come in two lines. What should I write so that it comes in one line?

[image]

One thing is that if I display less columns then it comes one line (in the above pic I had set the option to display all columns, although they are not visible in the truncated screenshot). This can be seen in below pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183502/16891669). It modifies the CSS of the style option of dataframe.

I'm putting the code for a quick reference here or if the link gets corrupted in future.

```py
# @RomuloPBenedetti's answer, check out the link
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'white-space: nowrap !important;'}])
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.set_option` sets one single option at the time. If you want to set multiple options you have to call it multiple times.

In your case that would be:

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
```

Alternatively you can set all these options using a for loop:

```py
options = {'display.max_rows': None, 
           'display.max_columns': None, 
           'display.max_colwidth', None}

for option, value in options.items():
    pd.set_option(option, value)
```

Comment: don't use a list comprehension for side effects, use a classical loop: `for option, value in options.items(): pd.set_option(option, value)`

Comment: I didn't know that could cause any issues, thanks for poiting it out! I'm going to fix my answer.

Comment: It's just bad practice, this creates a list of `[None, None, None]` uselessly ([more on this in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)). You can use it for code golf ;)

Comment: btw, no need to credit me ;)

Comment: It's still not working. Actually I had tried this before and it was not working so I just put all the statements into one. I've updated the screenshot, you can look into that

Comment: Also if I display less no. of columns then the display is fine, (I've updated in the question). So, I think there must be some other option to set.